# What is the largest known size of a CouchDB cluster and/or database?

Tags: nosql, couchdb

What is the largest known size of a CouchDB cluster and/or database in terms of bytes of storage, #s of documents, and/or #s of nodes?

Comment: Is this out of curiosity or does your application really need to store that much data? More insight into the core problem you're trying to solve will bring more answers.

Comment: When someone says "it's scalable", there's always a limit based on how far it's actually scaled in a real app.  I'm trying to assess how "scalable" CouchDB is.  More than curiosity, but the apps I deal with have 100s of TB and sometimes PB.

Answer (score 3):

This is a difficult one to know for sure, especially since it's always changing.  However, there is a page on the CouchDB wiki that may prove useful: [CouchDB in the wild](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/COUCHDB/CouchDB+in+the+wild).

Comment: it's not always changing.  I could do with rough estimates as well.  10 nodes?  100 nodes?  1000 nodes?  1 GB, 1 TB, 1 PB, 1M docs, 1B docs, etc...

Comment: I've heard both the BBC and meebo have large installations, but no details on how big.